# Which is the best way to get the values of checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I was curious about the best practice with checkboxes using methods of jQuery or JavaScript. Imagine a bunch of checkboxes inside a form, every row with 1 checkbox (the value is unique), click about 2 of them and simple use those values in an array...

The question is with educational motives, not really an issue, I worked with a project and made a very large code to work with checkboxes,

HTML:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="1" name="group" onclick="agregarDel("1")"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function agregarDel(id)
{
  if(document.getElementById(id).checked)
  {
          eliminar.push(document.getElementById(id).name);
  }else{
          var aux = eliminar.indexOf(document.getElementById(id).name);
          if(aux !== -1) eliminar.splice(aux, 1);
  }
}
```

The code above is just some poor example of what I was thinking. The idea is to find the best and more efficient way to get an ARRAY of values with the checked items.

Comment: This is a very vague question...

Comment: Is there a certain issue you are worried about? Or just generally worried?

Comment: _Which is the best way_. So what ways do you know?

Comment: Your example wouldn't really be useful. Your array gets recreated everytime and is also only available in the function scope.

Comment: @FillipPeyton I want to learn the best way to get the values from a group of checkboxes!

Comment: How would that function work @bjb568? What is `e`?

Comment: @putvande sorry I just write some random code while loading the actual code from git haha

Comment: @putvande there is the code working in my project, any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the best way to do that, the only way to answer is by doing some benchmarking...

I coded 3 different methods and measured the time they took to solve the problem.

**Method 1**

Using jQuery to find the checkboxes and then .prop('checked') to filter the checked ones

Time: *51ms*

**Method 2**

Using jQuery to find the checkboxes filtered within the selector $('input:checked')

Time: *14ms*

**Method 3**

Without jQuery

Time: *7ms*

Here's the code if you want to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/KcBEj/8/

```
//
// method 1
//

hola = [];
$('input').each(function(i,el){
    if($(el).prop('checked')){
        hola.push($(el).val());
    }
});

//
// method 2
//

hola = [];
$('input:checked').each(function(i,el){
    hola.push($(el).val());
});

//
// method 3
//

hola = [];
elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i=0,n=elems.length;i<n;i++){
    if(elems[i].getAttribute('checked') == 'checked') {
        hola.push(elems[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
}
```